# How to insert a node after another node using doubly linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I want to insert a node after another node in a doubly-linked list but when I provide such a key that doesn't exist in the Linked list then this method gives me an error. How should I fix this error? here is my code. Thanks in Advance.

```
{
   public void AddAfter(int insertAfter, int data) 
   {
   DLNode n = new DLNode(data);
   DLNode curr = head;
   if(head == null)
       head = n;
   else
   {
       while(curr.Data != insertAfter && curr != null) 
       {
           curr = curr.next;
       }
       if(curr != null) 
       {
           n.next = curr.next;
           n.prev = curr;
           n.next.prev = n;
           curr.next = n;
           NumNodes++;
           
           
       }
       else
           System.out.println("The Key "+insertAfter+" doesn't exist: ");
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error exactly? The more we know the easier it is for us. Include the call and the output, and probably you should include the full source code for the List too. As an additional topic: without a matching insertAfter value, your while loop WILL result in curr=null. So rewrite your check to `while(curr != null && curr.Data != insertAfter)` so that curr is checked for null first, so `curr.Data`will not throw NPE.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

> ... but when I provide such a key that doesn't exist in the Linked list then this method gives me an error.

The problem occur in your while loop condition (e.g., `curr.Data != insertAfter && curr != null`). Here, you are first accessing the `data` field of the `curr` variable and then checking whether `curr` is null or not.

> How should I fix this error?

You need to do it in reverse order. The following code should solve your problem.

```
public void AddAfter(int insertAfter, int data) {
    DLNode n = new DLNode(data);
    DLNode curr = head;
    
    if(head == null) {
        head = n;
    }
    else {
        while(curr != null && curr.Data != insertAfter) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        if(curr != null) {
            n.next = curr.next;
            n.prev = curr;
            n.next.prev = n;
            curr.next = n;
            NumNodes++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The Key "+insertAfter+" doesn't exist: ");
        }
    }
}
```